# Как правильно получить значение scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При достижении определённого значения скрола в блоке, должно выполняться какой то код. Но он не работает. Почему?

```
var scroll =  $('#block').scrollTop();
   if (scroll == 100) {
   alert('123');
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9hk2gngd/

Comment: вы точно в 100 никогда не попадете https://jsfiddle.net/9hk2gngd/1/

Comment: спасибо! теперь понятно

Comment: @splash58, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var x = elmnt.scrollLeft; //горизонтальный
  var y = elmnt.scrollTop; //вертикальный

  if (y > 100) {
   // 100 - значение в пикселях (если больше делать что-то)
  }
}
```